# How make a TSV processing golang program that is as efficient as `cut`?

Tags: csv, go, awk, cut

I have the following Go program to process a TSV input. But it is slower than `awk` and `cut`. I know `cut` uses string manipulate tricks to achieve a fast performance.

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cut.c

Is it possible to achieve the same performance as `cut` with Go (or at least better than `awk`)? What should things be used in Go to achieve a better performance?

```
$ ./main_.sh | indent.sh 
time ./main.go 10 < "$infile" > /dev/null

real    0m1.431s
user    0m0.978s
sys 0m0.436s
time cut -f 10 < "$infile" > /dev/null

real    0m0.252s
user    0m0.225s
sys 0m0.025s
time awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -e '{ print $10 }' < "$infile" > /dev/null

real    0m1.134s
user    0m1.108s
sys 0m0.024s

$ cat.sh main_.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

infile=$(mktemp)
seq 10000000 | paste -s -d $'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n' > "$infile"
set -v
time ./main.go 10 < "$infile" > /dev/null
time cut -f 10 < "$infile" > /dev/null
time awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -e '{ print $10 }' < "$infile" > /dev/null

$ cat main.go
#!/usr/bin/env gorun
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    idx, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    col := idx - 1

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := strings.TrimRight(scanner.Text(), "\n")
        fields := strings.Split(line, "\t")
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", fields[col])
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by profiling your app. Working solely with strings, and repeatedly allocating new ones is likely the problem.

Comment: @JimB I am still new to Go. How to avoid repeatedly allocating new strings?

Comment: use `[]byte` rather than `string`, and reuse the slices when possible.

Comment: @JimB Could you show the complete code about how to change the program? I am still not familiar with Go yet about where and how to make the change.

Comment: Call [Bytes](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner.Bytes) instead of Text.  Use [bytes.Split](https://godoc.org/bytes#Split) on the result or use [bytes.IndexByte](https://godoc.org/bytes#IndexByte) to find the split points.

Comment: Oh, and looking more closely here, why are you trying to use go like a scripting language? --  `#!/usr/bin/env gorun`?? Your example here is adding the compile time to the executing time. Just compile the program normally.

Comment: @JimB `#!/usr/bin/env gorun` is not a problem for my application. It only takes some time upon the first run. For later runs, the code will not be compiled again. It only adds up a little time to find the already compiled code and run it. So it will not cause much slow down especially given my input is very large.

Comment: Even if it does cache the binary (I've never seen gorun in use anywhere), it's still adding unnecessary variables to your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you profile the application, it will show most of the time is spent in

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", fields[col])
```

The main issue there is really the 10000000 syscalls you're making to write to stdout, so making stdout buffered will significantly reduce the execution time. Removing the overhead of the `fmt` calls will help even further.

The next step would be to reduce allocations, which you can do by using byte slices rather than strings. Combining these would lead to something like

```
stdout := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
defer stdout.Flush()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Bytes()
    fields := bytes.Split(line, []byte{'\t'})
    stdout.Write(fields[col])
    stdout.Write([]byte{'\n'})
}
```

Comment: This code is still over 30% slower than `cut`. Is there anything else in Go that can further improve its performance?

Comment: @user1424739: on my system the go program takes `0m2.353s` while cut takes `0m2.591s`. You'll need to come up with a better benchmark and profile the program to figure out what else could be trimmed.

Comment: @user1424739: if I were to take a guess, the next slowest part is the allocations in `bytes.Split`, so manually parsing the line without allocating is the next step.

Comment: There seems to be more than one way to profile Go programs. Which way would you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: @user1424739: all ways use the `pprof` tool, it's just a matter of how you set it up. The easiest way is to setup a proper benchmark and use `go test` which can output a profile directly.

Comment: `@JimB`: `bufio.Scanner.Bytes` may fail to capture the input line when the input line is too long. To make the code robust `bufio.Reader.ReadString` should be better.

Comment: @user1424739: yes, I was making the minimal change from your example, but the scanner line is limited to `MaxScanTokenSize`. If that's not acceptable, using the `bufio.Reader` directly is better. Though if you're benchmarking, `ReadString` is just re-introducing more copies if data again.  Unless you need the entire line as a string, [`ReadSlice`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadSlice) will allow you to only copy the data you require.

Comment: `@JimB`: `ReadSlice` only allow a single byte deliminator, which is not acceptable for my application. For this reason, it seems that I have to stick with `ReadString`. I'd wish `ReadSlice` could deal with an arbitrary byte array though.

Comment: I don't understand. `ReadString` and `ReadSlice` both take the same arguments. If you want more complex splitting, use a scanner with the `SplitFunc` that does what you want. If you want to be able to handle arbitrarily long lines, set an arbitrarily large max buffer size.

Comment: `@JimB`: my mistake. Yes, both `ReadString` and `ReadSlice` take the same argument.